# How to check value inside dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have dictionary with field `canServeInvalid`

I know that value inside is true. I prove this by printing to console `print(marker.userData["canServeInvalid"])` which returns

```
Optional(true)
```

But if I check its value like this

```
    if marker.userData["canServeInvalid"] != true {

        self.window?.canServeInvalid.hidden = true
        print("preved")

    }
```

I got `preved` printed, but I know there is true inside.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to compare `Optional(true)` and `true`

You should try to unwrap an optional using `if let` or `guard`

```
//if your userData is optional also
    if let userData = marker.userData {
        if let value = userData["canServeInvalid"] {

            if value {
                //do your stuff here
            } else {
                self.window?.canServeInvalid.hidden = true
                print("preved")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in my case there is always something inside - true or false, it cannot be empty

Comment: @Alexeyk by default, a value from dictionary is always optional :)

Comment: you right about default this is the main issue. Your code dont work, xcode tries to change "if value {" to "if value != nil  {"

Comment: @Alexeyk I'm not sure what is the type of your marker.userData :) In this cause, you can do twice unwrap to get your value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101318/discussion-between-breek-and-alexey-k).